# Is wine installed?

Tags: wine

I downloaded `wine1.6` from `winehq.org` and did the following

```
 ./configure --enable-win64 --without-freetype
make
make install
```

Now when I right click on `.exe` >`open with wine windows program loader` nothing happens.
Also `wine --version` says `no command wine found`
Trying `open with` with right-click on exe shows following dialogue box. 
[image]

Comment: In my case.Wine has been installed.But when I run "wine --version" in terminal on ubuntu.The terminal returns nothing.If I right click the *.exe run by wine,Nothing happens too.

Answer (score 4):

If `wine --version` returns `wine: command not found` the probabilities that you didn't installed it are high. You may want go for the safe path and install wine using apt:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

That will 100% sure install wine correctly.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install wine` requires online connection i guess. But i want to install the downloaded packages.

Answer (score 0):

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep wine
```

If the output of the above command displays wine,then you installed wine.If not install wine by running,

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Comment: that command doesn't display anything. But `apt-get` requires internet connection and i am on very very slow network. isn't it possible just to install the wine package i've downloaded?